# getting multipart and non-multipart form input params together in a submit button using Spring/Ajax/JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have spent quite a bit of time on this and haven't been able to figure this out. 
I have a jsp page with text input parameters and a image file upload field. How can I send all this form parameters with text and file to the controller. I am able to send either the text parameters or file but not both. Pl. help.

**JSP file**

```
<form name ="newSectionSubmitForm" id="newSectionSubmitForm"  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

  <td>
     <input type="text" name='imageName0'  class="form-control"/>
  </td>


 <td>
    <input type="file" id='imageFile0' name='imageFile0' class="form-control" />
 </td>

  <button onclick="submitNewSection('submitNewSection.html' ,'newwSectionSubmitForm');return false;">Submit Section</button>

</form>
```

**JS**

```
function postAjaxDataForImageFile(initiatingElement, targetElement, targetUrl, form,
    imageFile, successCallback) {



  var $targetElement = $('#' + targetElement);

  var serializedFormData = new FormData(form);


  serializedFormData.append("file", imageFile0.files[0]);


  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    data : serializedFormData,
    url : targetUrl,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

    success : function(data) {
        processRedirect(data);

        $targetElement.html(data);
        $targetElement.show();


        if (successCallback != null) {
            successCallback(data);
        }
    },
    error : function(xhr, httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errorId = xhr.getResponseHeader("errorId");

        var errorMsg = xhr.getResponseHeader("errorMessage");

        if (errorId != null && errorId != undefined) {
            $("#page_error").html(
                    "An unexpected error has occurred.  Error Id: "
                            + errorId);
        } else {
            $("#page_error").html("An unexpected error has occurred.");

        }
    },

});
```

}

**Controller File**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/submitNewSection.html")
public String submitNewSection(MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

Iterator<String> itr =  req.getFileNames();
MultipartFile mpf = req.getFile(itr.next());
multipartFile.add(mpf);

// code working fine so far

String imageName= req.getParameter("imageName0")); //giving null instead of value

//also tried
String imageName= request.getParameter("imageName0")); //still null instead of value

}
```

My spring xml has this bean info:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"                                                 class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" /> 

</bean>
```

How can I get both the form params and file input in the controller. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For whomever looking for a similar solution. Basically if you need array of file inputs you can get it in this manner -  MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
MultipartFile file = multipartRequest.getFile(filename);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best way is to use ajaxForm which works for all browsers.so in your case

```
$("#newSectionSubmitForm").ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function () {
            var percentVal = '0%';

        },
        resetForm: true,
        uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        },
        beforeSerialize: function ($Form, options) {

            return true;
        },
        success: function (data, status, xhr, $form) {

        //do whatever

        }
});
```

and on server side do it as fellow

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitNewSection.html", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    @ResponseBody
    public String submitNewSection(@RequestParam("imageFile0") MultipartFile file,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session) throws IOException {



  //You can get other parameters like 

   String yourParameter = request.getParameter("imageName0");

   //And play with your Multipart object like

    if (null != file && !file.isEmpty()) {
       //Do whatever

     }


}
```

**Updated**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitNewSection.html", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
        @ResponseBody
        public String submitNewSection(@RequestParam(value="imageFile0",required=false) MultipartFile file1,@RequestParam(value="imageFile1",required=false) MultipartFile file2,@RequestParam(value="imageFile2",required=false) MultipartFile file3,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                HttpSession session) throws IOException {



      //You can get other parameters like 

       String yourParameter = request.getParameter("imageName0");

       //And play with your Multipart object like

        if (null != file1 && !file1.isEmpty()) {
           //Do whatever

         }

        if (null != file2 && !file2.isEmpty()) {
           //Do whatever

         }
        if (null != file3 && !file3.isEmpty()) {
           //Do whatever

         }





    }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the code snippet. It worked perfectly well! :) Not sure why the FormData way was not working but AjaxForm worked out well. Sorry, can't vote up since not enough reputations but greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it possible to get array of files this way. Lets say I have imageFile0, imageFile1, imageFile2 to be passed, is this possible to get with RequestParam ? And these values 0,1,2 are in a table row. Thanks.

Comment: yes! see my updated answer.If you have known number of files then you can do is like this...if not then you can have same name for all the file element in html and can get that array in a array of file using RequestParam.

Answer (score 0):

you can use formdata for fileupload but this work for only html5 supported browsers.

```
var form = $('form')[0]; 
var formData = new FormData(form);
$.ajax({
    url: 'submitNewSection.html',
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
});
```

And if you want it to work even for older browsers you can use iframe with form for fileupload.

Comment: This is what I have done. It is in my JS file as shown, but it doesnt seem to work. I do have Chrome 35 and it does support html5, but I dont seem to get the file input and text input together. I can get either of them but not both.